# Support for User Defined Types for java in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there support for UDT for java in spark?

Does JavaSQLContext support User Defined Types(UDTs) when converting JavaRDD to JavaSchemaRDD?

If yes, is there any sample to demonstrate the capability.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the simplest way is to have it inferred via reflection. [See the SparkSQL documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) and click on the Java tab. Then, read the section labelled

> Inferring the Schema Using Reflection

**Edit from comments**

I'm not sure that the Java API is as easily fleshed out as the scala one, so it seems in order to nest types you may need to build the schema yourself:

```
//First create the address
List<StructField> addressFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
fields.add(DataType.createStructField("street", DataType.StringType, true));    
StructType addressStruct = DataType.createStructType(addressFields)

//Then create the person, using the address struct
List<StructField> personFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
fields.add(DataType.createStructField("name", DataType.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataType.createStructField("age", DataType.IntType, true));
fields.add(DataType.createStructField("address", addressStruct, true));

StructType schema = DataType.createStructType(fields);
```

Comment: That section uses a Java Bean with simple Data Types. What if, the Person class (in example) has a property with a custom type called Address.

Comment: Did you give it a try? It infers the whole way down.

Comment: yes, I tried. I get "scala.MatchError: class [Address; (of class java.lang.Class)"

Comment: @malli Try my edit. If that doesnt work, then Ill have to actually write some Java instead of Scala

Comment: What version of spark is this?

Comment: I forget - probably a higher 1.x based on the date and the info provided.